# VBA For loop initialising working in one sub, almost identical sub not working

Tags: vba, for-loop, initialization

I am trying to loop through headers of columns in VBA, (which may get moved around), by finding the header name, then hiding those columns.
The hiding part works fine, but I decided to do a simple 'unhide' and got thrown an error:
Run-time error '92': For loop not initialized.

The only thing I've changed is whether or not I'm making the current selection hidden or not (True or False). I tried changing the variable names, thinking maybe something was getting mucked up by sharing them between the subs, but that didn't help.

The code for the WORKING 'hide' sub is below:

```
Public Sub Activate_Print_Mode()

 Dim SearchArray() As Variant SearchArray = Array("ISBN", "Sub Title",
 "Paper Cut Off", "Despatch Date (ExW)", "Printer Location", "UK WH
 ETA", "Suggested Pub ExW", "Suggested Pub ExUK", "INDENT / STATUS",
 "UK VAT Price", "FX", "GB Net Price", "AU Price + Freight", "S/A",
 "Discount", "PRICE NOTES", "ORDERED", "Budget Value", "Misc Specs")

 Dim element As Variant

 For Each element In SearchArray
     ' perform search, hide column
     'counter = counter + 1
     Rows("3:3").Select
     Selection.Find(What:=element, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
         MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
     ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select


     Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True


     Next element
      ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

 End Sub
```

The non-working 'show' sub is below:

```
 Public Sub DeActivate_Print_Mode()

 Dim DispSearchArray() As Variant SearchArray = Array("ISBN", "Sub
 Title", "Paper Cut Off", "Despatch Date (ExW)", "Printer Location",
 "UK WH ETA", "Suggested Pub ExW", "Suggested Pub ExUK", "INDENT /
 STATUS", "UK VAT Price", "FX", "GB Net Price", "AU Price + Freight",
 "S/A", "Discount", "PRICE NOTES", "ORDERED", "Budget Value", "Misc
 Specs")

 Dim DispElement As Variant


 For Each DispElement In DispSearchArray
     ' perform search, hide column
     'counter = counter + 1
     Rows("3:3").Select
     Selection.Find(What:=element, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
         MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
     ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
     Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

     Next DispElement
      ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

 End Sub
```

What gives?

Comment: Make sure all range objects are assigned to there relative parent sheets.  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(3)`

Comment: "Non-working" is not a good description of what happens when you run the second example.  But it doesn't work because `Find()` doesn't locate values in hidden columns/rows.  You'll need to loop over the cells instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Find()` doesn't locate values in hidden columns/rows

I would do something like this (untested)

```
Sub hidethem()
    Set_Print_Mode True
End Sub
Sub showthem()
    Set_Print_Mode False
End Sub

Public Sub Set_Print_Mode(doHide As Boolean)

    Dim SearchArray As Variant
    Dim m, rng As Range, sht As Worksheet
    Dim element As Variant

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    SearchArray = Array("ISBN", "Sub Title", _
    "Paper Cut Off", "Despatch Date (ExW)", "Printer Location", "UK WHETA", _
    "Suggested Pub ExW", "Suggested Pub ExUK", "INDENT / STATUS", _
    "UK VAT Price", "FX", "GB Net Price", "AU Price + Freight", "S/A", _
    "Discount", "PRICE NOTES", "ORDERED", "Budget Value", "Misc Specs")

    For Each element In SearchArray
        m = Application.Match(element, sht.Rows(3), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = sht.Columns(m)
            Else
                Set rng = Application.Union(rng, sht.Columns(m))
            End If
        End If
    Next element

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Hidden = doHide

    sht.Range("A1").Select

 End Sub
```

Could be made even more generic by adding a parameter for the header row and one for the array of headers...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Public Sub UnHideColumns()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastCell As Integer
Dim DispSearchArray() As Variant

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
lastCell = ws.Range("1:1").End(xlToRight).Column
DispSearchArray = Array("ISBN", "Sub Title", "Paper Cut Off", "Despatch Date (ExW)", "Printer Location", "UK WH ETA", "Suggested Pub ExW", "Suggested Pub ExUK", "INDENT / STATUS", "UK VAT Price", "FX", "GB Net Price", "AU Price + Freight", "S/A", "Discount", "PRICE NOTES", "ORDERED", "Budget Value", "Misc Specs")

For Each Header In DispSearchArray
    For j = 1 To lastCell
        If Cells(1, j) = Header Then
            ws.Cells(1, j).Select
            Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next j
Next Header

Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

I feel like it's a little more transparent, but that's just me. Give it a try!